# How to draw the rect canvas on another view in android?

Tags: android, canvas, ontouchlistener

Hi I am new in android also new in Stackoverflow.
I want create simple crop apps so I use the on image view and apply the on touch listener on this.when I touch on this. I draw simple and small default `rect`. After this when I drag the cursor on the screen I want to increase the size of `rect` in run time. So apply the attributes array on `onDraw` method.but I can`t do it. my code is below.

my Draw View Class

```
public class DrawView extends View 
{   

Paint paint ;

Canvas myCanvas;

float []atr;

public DrawView(Context context) 
{
    super(context);

}

public DrawView(Context context, float [] atr) 
{
      super(context);
      this.atr=atr;
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);     
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);     
    canvas.drawRect(atr[0], atr[1], atr[2],atr[3], paint);
    //System.err.println("After Call on Draw Method");      
}
}
```

and i use in this class which my parent class.

```
enter code hereContext myContext;
RelativeLayout relMainLayout,relHeaderLayout,relBelowLayout;    

DrawView drawView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myContext=DrawRectActivity.this;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   

    int layoutId = myContext.getResources().getIdentifier("main","layout",getPackageName());

    relMainLayout = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(layoutId,null);

    relHeaderLayout=(RelativeLayout) relMainLayout.findViewById(R.id.relHeaderLayout);

    relBelowLayout=(RelativeLayout) relMainLayout.findViewById(R.id.relBelowLayout);

    /*int[] atr={10,10,00,00};
    drawView=new DrawView(myContext,atr);
    drawView.bringToFront();
    drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams drawParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,200);
    drawParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, relHeaderLayout.getId());      
    relMainLayout.addView(drawView, drawParams);    */

    setContentView(relMainLayout);
   //drawView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    //relMainLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
    float x,y;
    float incx=5,incy=5;
    x=event.getX();
    y=event.getY();     

    switch (event.getActionMasked()) 
    {       
    case  MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        System.err.println("X-->"+x);

        System.err.println("Y-->"+y);

        float[] atr={x,y,x+incx,y+incy};
        drawView=new DrawView(myContext,atr);
        drawView.bringToFront();
        //drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams drawParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,200);
        drawParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, relHeaderLayout.getId());      
        relMainLayout.addView(drawView, drawParams);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        float x1=event.getX();
        float y1=event.getY();
        incx=x1+incx;
        incy=y1+incy;
        float[] at1={x,y,incx,incy};
        drawView=new DrawView(myContext,at1);
        drawView.bringToFront();            
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        System.err.println("Up X-->"+x);
        System.err.println("Up y-->"+y);

        System.err.println("Up X-->"+incx);
        System.err.println("Up y-->"+incy);


        break;

    default:

        break;
    }



    /*int[] atr={100,100,00,00};        
    DrawView drawView2=new DrawView(myContext, atr);
    Bitmap myCanvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();
    myCanvas.setBitmap(myCanvasBitmap); 
    //canvas.setDensity(BIND_AUTO_CREATE);      
    drawView2.draw(myCanvas);       */  
    return false;
}
```

and also use the touch event on this.

Comment: Well I could be wrong but I think you're not getting any changes because you create new `DrawView`s all the time and not altering the showing one in the first place. I'd add some clearing methods to your `DrawView` and work with the same object created at an earlier point, maybe your `onCreate()` for example.

Comment: i want draw in it run time but when touch then draw the rect but with old parameter.but i want pass the new parameter.